# “Singleton Session Bean” to store application wide informations Java EE 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton

I write a Java ee 6 application on a jboss-as-7 application server. I want to have a “Singleton Session Bean” to store application wide informations in a list “mediaDataList”.

A statless session bean “ClassA“  write some object to this list and a webservice reads the  informations in the “mediaDataList” list.

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.WRITE)
public class MediaDataSafe {

    private final List<MediaData> mediaDataList = new ArrayList<MediaData>();

    @Inject
    Logger log;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        // read from HD and store in mediaDataList
    }


    // just read the list...
    public List<MediaData> getMediaDataList() {
        return mediaDataList;
    }

    // write to list
    public void writeMediaDataSafe(...) {
        mediaDataList.add(auraMediaData);
    }
}


@Stateless
public class ClassA {

    @Inject
    MediaDataSafe mediaDataSafe;

    //write in list of singleton
    public void write(...) {
        mediaDataSafe.writeMediaDataSafe(...);
    }
}

@WebService(serviceName = "MyWebService", endpointInterface = "com.WebService")
public class MyWebService implements com.bla.WebService {

    //...

    @Inject
    transient MediaDataSafe mediaDataSafe;

    //read from list in singleton
    public MediaList getMediaList(...){
        mediaDataSafe.getMediaDataList(...);
    }
}
```

My problem is, it seems that there exists two “signleton bean” in my system! If “ClassA “ write some new values to the list, I can't read this new values with my webservice. 
The webservice returns always the same list. (it contains the state on init!)

What do I wrong? Do I misunderstanding something here about “Singleton Session Bean”?

Comment: Depending on the specifics of your application, you probably want to look into Application Scoped Beans, instead of trying to make a session bean application scoped. Application Scoped Beans are marked in your descriptor file, and only one will exist on a server.

Comment: Yes i know how application scoped beans work. But what i want, is to handle this on my business layer not on web layer... therefore i prefer a singleton. But why doesn't work this....?

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine so far for me, since a Singleton is instantiated once per application, the only reasons I can think of leading possibly to the described behaviour is something in the direction of several deployments of the same application.

Maybe it helps to read the following parts of the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) carefully to find the problem:

- [Singleton Session Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html#gipim)
- [Singleton Session Bean Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html)

Comment: Actually i may have something like several deployments. I have a business tier (contains my singleton) which is used by a web tier (for admin console) and a communication tier (webservice). What i don't understand is that my writing and my reading of the list go through the webservice. In this case for my webservice should still exist just one singleton or not?

Comment: What i forgot to write, is that the writing in the list is implemented  by a message driven bean. Does this have some strange impact?

Comment: @Gatschet If there are really more than one instance or if it gets re-initialized somehow, you can check by setting breakpoints or add logging to check the object id and if it runs through the constructor twice. Besides that, it should not matter which component calls your Singleton, it should only exist once.

Comment: No there are two instances with also two different lists in my application. I checked that by comparing the object id. Any ideas, how I can solve or analyze my problem?

Comment: Well, then it must be the case, that you have 2 different applications, each having its own instance of the singleton. Have you tried having your Singleton provide the web service and then consume it from different clients? Independently, check out [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/EJBSingletonWebServices/SingletonWebServices.html), which uses Singleton and WebService in combination.